# Template Return Type with Default Value

Tags: c++, templates

So in writing a C++ template class, I have defined a method that returns an object of the templated type, as such:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    T GetFoo()
    {
        T value;

        //Do some stuff that might or might not set the value of 'value'

        return value;
    }
 };

int main() {

    Foo<int> foo;

    foo.GetFoo();

    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following warning:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘T Foo<T>::GetFoo() [with T = int]’:
prog.cpp:15: warning: ‘value’ is used uninitialized in this function
```

I understand why this is happening - I am returning an uninitialized `int` as part of `GetFoo`.  The thing is, if I were to use `Foo<SomeClass>`, the line `T value;` would initialize `value` using the default constructor of `SomeClass`.

I have managed to suppress this warning by doing the following:

```
    T GetFoo()
    {
        T value = T();

        //Do some stuff that might or might not set the value of 'value'

        return value;
    }
```

This seems to work for primitive types (such as `int` and `float`) and classes, at least so long as that class has a default constructor and copy constructor.  My question is - is this the accepted way of solving this problem?  Are there any side effects of this I should know about?

Comment: This is the canonical approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615549/how-to-get-the-default-value-of-any-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds OK, if the class has no copy constructor, you will not be able to return it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
T t;
```

Default constructs objects, yet declares uninitialized built-in types.  There is no syntax to 'default construct' a local variable.

Therefore it's not trivial to write generic code that initializes a variable, whether built-in or class.

Wrapping the type into a member variable, however, may present a workaround that does not need copy construction (apart from the return statement):

```
template< typename T > struct Initializer {
   T t;
   Initializer()
   :t() // ====> default construction, works for classes _and_ built-in
   {}
};
```

Using this wrapper, you can build your code in a generic way:

```
template<typename T> T foo() {
  Initializer<T> i;
  // fill in i.t to your liking
  return i.t;
}
```

See a full-blown snippet at [codepad](http://codepad.org/w15PqPLu).

Answer (score 3):

Indeed that's the standard way to solve the problem. I don't believe there should be any side effects to worry about in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> This seems to work for primitive types
>   (such as int and float) and classes,
>   at least so long as that class has a
>   copy constructor

For classes, not only [public] copy-constructor, you also need `public` default constructor!

> My question is - is this the accepted way of solving this problem?

Usually it's a good idea to provide `public` default constructor. STL containers use it all the time! If you don't have one, most (or maybe, all) STL containers would not work at many occasions.

See this example with `private` default constructor: http://ideone.com/EdPLu

Comment: Er, yes, I meant to say that.  Let me edit it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to return an un-initialized value from this function? Sounds like it could lead to a whole lot of crap later down the line.

Why don't you use an appropriate wrapper - if you have access to boost, consider `boost::optional`. This way, if you don't initialize it, it can be tested properly.

Comment: A default constructed object might be precisely what he wants though.

Comment: For the purpose of this class (and function), the uninitialized (or default) value was deemed acceptable.

Comment: @Mark B, *depends* on what goes where the comment is I guess, and how it's used on return...

Comment: @James, there is a *difference* between *uninitialized* and *default constructed*, for example, if it's as simple as `int`, you have no way of testing the former...

Comment: This is true.  Will look again at the expected behavior and make sure this is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Boost addresses this problem in one of its utility template classes, namely [boost::value_initialized](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/value_init.htm) and its relatives.