# Template functions: default construction without copy-constructing in C++

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor, default-constructor

Considering

```
struct C { 
   C()            { printf("C::C()\n"          ); }
   C(int)         { printf("C::C(int)\n"       ); }
   C( const C& )  { printf("copy-constructed\n"); }
};
```

And a template function

```
template< typename T > void foo(){
    // default-construct a temporary variable of type T
    // this is what the question is about.
    T t1;       // will be uninitialized for e.g. int, float, ...
    T t2 = T(); // will call default constructor, then copy constructor... :(
    T t3();     // deception: this is a local function declaration :(
}

int main(){
    foo<int>();
    foo<C  >();
}
```

Looking at `t1`, it will not be initialized when `T` is e.g. `int`.  On the other hand, `t2` will be *copy-constructed from* a default constructed temporary.

The question: is it possible in C++ to default-construct a generic variable, other than with template-fu?

Comment: for those who think... I've seen this kinda question before, today... They're right.  But this very aspect to that question remained unanswered.

Comment: @xtofl: what is *template-fu*?

Comment: @Nawaz: The C++ version of *kung fu*.

Comment: @Ben: Cool. Is this term popular enough in C++ community? Or newly invented?

Comment: @Nawaz : [anything]-fu is popular. Mostly seen in sentences like "My python-fu isn't strong enough".

Comment: @Nawaz: the postfix 'fu' is often used to indicate 'high skill'.  Analogous to the oft-used 'script-fu'.  Sorry to have con-fu-zed you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a trick you can use, using a local class:

```
template <typename T> void foo() {
    struct THolder {
        T obj;
        THolder() : obj() { } // value-initialize obj
    };

    THolder t1; // t1.obj is value-initialized
}
```

I think I read about this trick from an answer to another Stack Overflow question, but I am unable to find that question at the moment.

Alternatively, you can use the `boost::value_initialized<T>` class template, which basically does the same thing, with greater flexibility and consistency and with workarounds for buggy compilers.

In C++0x, it's much easier:  you can use an empty initializer list:

```
T obj{}; // obj is value-initialized
```

(To the best of my knowledge, only gcc 4.5+ supports C++0x initializer lists.  Clang and Visual C++ don't yet support them.)

Comment: I think you could have read it from my answer to said question :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300602/template-return-type-with-default-value/5300915#5300915

Comment: @xtofl:  Ah, so you already know of this trick.  To the best of my knowledge, it's the C++03 way to do it (in C++0x you can use an initializer list).  [I hadn't seen that question this morning; this trick was mentioned sometime last year]

Comment: I was waiting for someone to mention C++0x.  Could you give an example for that?

Comment: @xtofl:  I've added how this can be done with an empty C++0x initializer list.

Comment: @xtofl: In C++0x, that should be simply `X x{};` - However, it seems that at this time some compilers can (apparently mistakenly?!) invoke a constructor overload taking `initializer_list` if available (see http://ideone.com/Il93E and comment out the overload to compare).

Comment: Thanks.   This kinda answers my question: no, there is no way in C++<0x, but C++0x foresees in the 'empty' initializer list.

Comment: C++<0x looks like a big-headed, four-armed dude on a skateboard, or something.  ;-)

Comment: @UncleBens, yep mistakenly. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#990

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t care for the fact that the copy constructor must exist, and just want to prevent it being called:

Don’t worry: it won’t be. The copy constructor call **will** be elided in this situation. Always, and reliably – *even when you compile with optimizations disabled* (`-O0`).

Comment: "Always, and reliably" -- on every C++ compiler ever made, and even when the copy constructor is inaccessible?

Comment: @Ben To the first part: on all that matter. To the second part: I’ve addressed that in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: *"Always and reliably"* is a very tall claim!

Comment: @Nawaz This code is a fixed idiom and the standard explicitly mentions that compilers can optimize this. I’m reasonably sure that even not so recent compilers do the right thing. That said, I’m talking about the real world. Of course anyone could build a conforming compiler just to violate this one statement. But that’s not really relevant.

Comment: Although the compiler eliminates unnecessary copies, it would still require a copy constructor to be accessible.

Comment: Even Visual C++ 6 does it, _even in debug_. Can't find source for this anymore, though.

Comment: @Konrad: A slight variation, and the copy-constructor didn't get elided (causing all manner of grief): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305391/winsock-accept-returning-wsaenotsock-code-10038

Comment: @Ben Sorry but that’s a com-pur-letely different case. This question was specifically about default-constructing a templated value not about copy elision in return values. `T x = T()` is a common and known use-case because it’s often *necessary* to prevent the most vexing parse of `T x()` (and the likes). Every compiler vendor knows to expect that.

Comment: @Konrad: This question looks to me like it's about eliding the copy of the return value from the default constructor.  True the other example is not a default constructor, but it's otherwise similar.

Answer (score 0):

What is your real question? The default constructor is called for *t1* instance.

Comment: Yes, if `T` is a class type.  If `T` is, e.g., `int`, then `t1` will be left uninitialized.

Comment: well... it isn't for `int`.  I'll try to reformulate the question.

Comment: @James: but what is the point of the exercise?  Is it a trivia question?  Is it trying to automatically initialize variables?

Comment: It's trying to write generic code that works for classes as well as for built-in types, and does no overhead for either.

Answer (score 0):

> T t2 = T(); // will call default constructor, then copy constructor... :(

Not on my compiler (VC2008). Output for me is...

```
C::C()
C::C()
```

Which is what I'd expect it to do. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's because the call to the copy constructor can be elided.  If the copy constructor was inaccessible or otherwise uncallable, then the `T t2 = T();` won't work.

Comment: Right, I get it now. Maybe the comment in the question needs to read "// Requires accessible copy constructor :("