# How to get the default value of any type

Tags: c++, templates

In C# I can write something like this:

```
    class AnyThing<T>
    {
        static public T Default = default(T);
    }

    static void Main ()
    {
        int i = AnyThing<int>.Default;
        Console.WriteLine (i==0);
        string s = AnyThing<string>.Default;
        Console.WriteLine (s == null);

    }
```

I intend to write a dictionary like template class in C++, I'd like the dict to return the default value (zero out) of the generic TVal type if the given key not be found. In C# the default(T) construct comes to rescue, while in C++ I'm not sure what is the appropriate way to do the same thing.

I've tried `T obj = {}` and `T* obj = {}` with gcc4.7, it works well. I'm just not so sure if it is the syntax defined by the language specification, if this kinda code will be portable cross compilers and platforms. Please help me with my doudt! Thanks in advance!

PS:

~~~~~~~~~~

To make sure the template get the default(zero out) value of ANY type, even of those that don't have callable default ctor, I employed following mechanism (inspired by avakar's answer):

```
template<class T>
struct AnyThing
{
    static const T& Default ;
private:
    static const char temp[sizeof(T)];
};

template<class T> const char AnyThing<T>::temp[] = {};
template<class T> const T& AnyThing<T>::Default =  *(T*)temp;

struct st
{
    double data;
    st()=delete;
};

int main()
{
    cout << (int)AnyThing<char*>::Default<<endl;    //0
    cout << AnyThing<int>::Default<<endl;       //0
    cout <<AnyThing<st>::Default.data<<endl;        //0
}
```

It looks ugly, but shouldn't cause any trouble, after all a zeroed out object is just a chunk of blank memory. Am I wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962600/what-is-the-c-cli-equivalent-to-cs-defaultt

Comment: I am not completely sure if this solves your problem, but I think [Boost.Value Initialized](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/value_init.htm) tries to address this very problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In C++ there is no something like `default` keyword in C#. Since initialization by default constructor of value of class-type will be failed, if default constructor is `private`. In C#, if default constructor is private, value of class-type will be initialized to `null`, since class-type is `reference-type`.

Initialition by `{}` is defined by language specification. It's C++11. In C++03 you should use

```
T obj = T();
```

As pointed by *bames53* in comment, when you want to initialize `T*` you should use

before C++11.

```
T* obj = 0;
```

or

```
T* obj = NULL;
```

in C++11.

```
T* obj = {};
```

or

```
T* obj = nullptr;
```

Comment: @Need4Steed, it works for pointer types if by "works" you mean that the default value of the pointer being null. "Works" is a short way of saying "meets my expectations"; like the longer phrase, it fails to reveal what the expected outcome actually is. But at least it's short,

Comment: @JesseGood `T *t = T*();` works fine though. `T t = T();` also works fine when T is a pointer type.

Comment: Indeed. Note that you can also do this outside templates: `int i = int();` , you don't need `Anything<T>`.

Comment: @MSalters `default(int)` in C# is also ok, so expression `int i = default(int);` is correct (verified in C# 4.0).

Comment: My mistake, `T *t = T*();` does not actually work. Since the default value for all pointers is the null pointer you could use `T *t = NULL;`. If you're using a C++11 compiler you should just prefer uniform initialization syntax, `T *t = {};` or `T *t{};`.

Comment: Note that `T` must be copyable here. There's a way to do this without the need for the copy constructor, see my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Taken literaly from "The C++ Programming Language, Third Edition by Bjarne Stroustrup":

BEGIN QUOTE

4.9.5 Initialization [dcl.init]

If an initializer is specified for an object, that initializer determines the initial value of an object. If no initializer is specified, a global (§4.9.4), namespace (§8.2), or local static object (§7.1.2, §10.2.4) (collectively called static objects) is initialized to 0 of the appropriate type. For example:

```
int a;  // means int a=0;
double d; // meands d=0;
```

Local variables (sometimes called automatic objects) and objects created on the free store (sometimes called dynamic objects or heap objects) are not initialized by default. For example:

```
void f()
{
   int x;   // x does not have a well-defined value
   // . . . 
}
```

Members of arrays and structures are default initialized or not depending on whether the array or structure is static. User-defined types may have default initialization defined (§10.4.2).

More complicated objects require more than one value as an initializer. This is handled by initializer lists delimited by { and } for C-style initialization of arrays (§5.2.1) and structures (§5.7).

For user-defined types with constructors, function-style argument lists are used (§2.5.2, §10.2.3). Note that an empty pair of parentheses () in a declaration always means ‘‘function’’ (§7.1). For example:

```
int a[] = {1,2};    // array initializer
Point z(1,2);       // function-style initializer (initialization by constructor)
int f();            // function declaration
```

END QUOTE

So, you can get the default value of any type form a static object of that type:

```
static T defaultT; // `defaultT' has de default value of type T
```

Comment: But I just found out that the `T()` solution stops working if I deleted the defaut ctor of T, or declared it as private, but in C# `default(T)` works anyway, so it doesn't literally work for ANY type! What a setback1

Comment: @Need4Steed Yes, since C# has reference types and value types. All class-types are reference-types and can be initialized by null, C++ has no such thing.

Comment: Best answer, directly from the inventor of C++. Why the heck does this answer have so few votes? For shame! Thanks, roy.

Comment: Best  solution, but TLDR answer. If only the last line were first.

Answer (score 6):

Create your own default keyword:

```
class default_t
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  operator T() const { return T(); }
};

default_t const default = default_t();
```

Use it like:

```
int myInt = default;
vector<string> myVector = default;
shared_ptr<string> myPtr = default;
```

Or with a slight semantic variation:

```
default_t const empty = default_t();

vector<Persons> fetchPersons()
{
  if (Database::isConnected())
  {
    return Database::fetchPersons();
  }

  return empty;
}
```

Comment: Interesting style. I'll have to play with this some. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

ForEveR's answer will not work if `T` doesn't have a copy constructor. In C++03, there is no way to zero-initialize a variable that is both generic and elegant. All that's left is the following trick.

```
T temp[1] = {};
T & obj = temp[0];
```

Here, `temp[0]` is zero-initialized and then bound to `obj`. No copy constructors are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it as of C++20:

```
constexpr auto default_value(const auto& value) {
  return std::decay_t<decltype(value)>{};
}

int main() {
  static_assert(default_value(std::string_view{"foo"}) == std::string_view{});
  static_assert(default_value(123) == 0);
  static_assert(default_value(&main) == nullptr);
}
```

If you already have the type `T` it'd just be `std::decay_t<T>{}` or `T{}` if you are sure that it is not a reference / array / ... (as those do not have a default value).

Comment: ROFL. That's *awful*!!! Only the authors of C++20 would think they are doing anyone any favors with THAT! Time to get rid of all the template programmers on the C++ standards committee, and put Bjarne Strousstrup back in charge!! (Bjarne is publicly on record bemoaning the sorry state of C++).

Comment: Sry. Just coming of the 3 days work trying to get C++20 co-routines to do *anything* sensible. So I'm not particularly happy with C++20 right now. But you're right. That *IS* how you'd do it in C++20.

Comment: what would you like to write instead ? if you don't care about performance at all you could do 

    auto default_value(auto value) { return decltype(value){}; }

but hopefully you wouldn't do it with unordered_map, boost::graph or other large types.

Comment: Also if I'm not mistaken in C++23 you could do instead 

     return decltype(auto{value}){};

but at some point you can't just perform introspection on your types without writing anything... how would you do it for instance in your language of choice ? I doubt it'd be a 3-liner like this

Comment: After 15 years of frozen language-spec, and 20 years of increasingly unusable and baroque revisions, I'd like the language committee to spend some time addressing usability, and add "default(declspec)" to the language. (easy since default is a reserved keyword)

Comment: And in my language of choice (c#), its "default(declspec)".  (Although its somewhat less of a pressing issue in languages where all variables have default values by default).

Answer (score 0):

on C++ 11 we can use `type{}` for initialization (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

so:

```cpp
int x{};//will work
decltype(x){};//as well as this
```

it can be used on default parameters also

```cpp
template<typename Prev,typename Param,int n>
struct Bond {
  const Prev& parent;
  const Param param;
  constexpr Bond(const Param param=Param{}):parent(Prev{}),param(param) {}
  constexpr Bond(const Prev& parent,const Param param):parent(parent),param(param) {}
};
```